# Call form method from another object method

Tags: c#

I tried to pass the Form through the reference but it giving:

> 'Form' does not contain a definition for and no extension method accepting a first argument of type 'Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here's the code:

```
    public class Foo
    {
      public void FooVoid()
      {
        Form1.FormVoid();
      }
    }

    public void FormVoid()
    {

    }

    public Program()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do here, calling a method on a view is not a good approach.
But getting to the actual answer, I suppose the FormVoid method is defined not in the Form1 class.

Comment: I would suggest a good book -  to be honest most of the learn c# books will guide you well through this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a class scoped variable and in the load event/constructor call you reference your main form. Not the best practice but you dont provide too much information about what you are trying to accomplish..

```
    public static Form1 form;

    public class Foo
    {
        public void FooVoid()
        {
            //Form1.FormVoid();

            //Then you have a reference to your Form1 and can call the method like this
            Form1.form.FormVoid()
        }
    }

    public void FormVoid()
    {

    }

    public Program()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form = this;
    }
```